# Google App Engine, http inside container considered a vulnerablity

Tags: node.js, containers, gcloud

We use Google App Engine and the provided load balancer to do SSL offloading for our API requests which are served by NodeJs. A third part is using Fortify to determine that even though it is https to the outside, because it is http inside the containers, it is considered a vulnerability.

Everything we read suggests setting the environment up this way.

Is this really a vulnerability and if so, how would we best mitigate against this without having to add paid certificates into our Node app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this really a vulnerability and if so, how would we best mitigate
> against this without having to add paid certificates into our Node
> app.

Yes, the proxy of HTTPS to HTTP is a vulnerability as data is decrypted in transit. However, the connection between the frontend and your application is very hard to exploit outside the Google data center. I am not aware of a method to exploit this item.

In the cloud and on-premises data centers, proxying of HTTPS to HTTP is very popular. This [offloads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS_acceleration) the CPU intensive process of encryption and decryption.

In security, there are almost always exceptions that need to be documented. This is one of them.

For the second part of your question, the proxy is HTTPS -> HTTP. This means that you cannot add your own SSL certificate to your backend code. If you did, you would have connection protocol errors.

If you must mitigate this problem, then you must select a different service and deploy your code with frontends/backends (web servers/proxies/load balancers) you configure and control.